# Object initialization in angular2

Tags: angular, webpack

I have an object `payment` and which initializes after successful http call, in response, it gets a key `account`, so to declare payment object I am declaring like `public payment = {}` (currently this don't have that `account` key). I am using `account` in different functions and since at the compile time payment is empty object webpack gives me this error `Property 'account' does not exist on type '{}'.`. But if I initialize payment object as `public payment = {account: ""}` this error goes away, but this I think is not a proper way so how I can prevent this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Payment` type:

```
class Payment {
    account: string // or whatever
}
```

And initialize like so:

```
public payment: Payment = new Payment();
```

This is not strictly necessary - the typescript compiler compiles your existing code fine.  But organizing your application pays off through code completion and better type checking as your application grows.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to start working with objects... you should have a javascript type called Payment that you can instantiate without data that has all the properties you expect.

Then on initialization of the main object, you'd have something like :

```
function Payment() {
  var self = this;
  self.Account = null;
}
function MyController() {
  var self = this;
  self.payment = new Payment();
}
```

This may, at first, seem unnecessary, but these object become very helpful once the application becomes more complicated, because it gives you a place to put functions and other derived properties you'll need in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

object needs to initialize in constructor if you wants to use in multiple methods.

find below code for your reference.

> **Component.cs**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'MyPage',
    templateUrl: 'mypage.component.html'
})

export class MyPageComponent {    
    public account: Account;

    constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.account = new Account();
    }
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: put Account into constructor and assign to local member, wtf is that coupling